# Twitter share button for iOS app

Tags: ios, twitter, icons, share

I'm creating a separate Twitter share button for my iOS app. The image for the twitter share button, am I allowed to make my own version of Twitter's logo for my app as long as users know the button is for twitter? Or am I only supposed to use the exact white bird and blue background image for my share button to indicate twitter? I can't seem to find anywhere on twitter for developers to download the twitter icon button to use for my iOS share button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules for using twitter's logo can be found here as well as links to download the logo for your use. 
https://about.twitter.com/press/brand-assets

> Don’t:
>
> - Use any other artwork from our site, such as the verified badge.
> - Create your own buttons or images using our logos unless technically necessary, such as in signature bars. If you do, use this resized
>     version of the Twitter bird
> - Use old versions or any other marks or logos to represent our brand